# How to compare list in dataframe to column entries to retrieve data

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe that I want to transform based on entries.
ID column should stay like it is.
y column is used as a reference to find the entry that needs to be replace the entries in the pairs column.

```
df_input= pd.DataFrame({
    'id': [111, 222, 333, 444],
    'y': [0, 1, 3, 4],
    'pairs': [[0], [1, 4], [0, 3], [4]]
           }
    )
```

```
df_output= pd.DataFrame({
    'id': [111, 222, 333, 444],
    'y': [0, 1, 3, 4],
    'pairs': [[111], [222, 444], [111, 333], [444]]
           }
    )
```

I tried the following but it does not result in my desired output.

```
def transform_df(df):
    id_to_list_map = df.set_index('y')['pairs'].to_dict()

    def modify_list(lst, id_value):
        return [id_value if i in id_to_list_map else i for i in lst]

    df2 = df.copy()
    df2['list'] = df2.apply(lambda row: modify_list(row['pairs'], row['id']), axis=1)

    return df2
```

currently it outputs

```
pd.DataFrame({
    'id': [111, 222, 333, 444],
    'y': [0, 1, 3, 4],
    'pairs': [[111], [444, 444], [333, 333], [444]]
           }
    )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a mapping dictionary then map the column to lookup the values from dictionary

```
d = df.set_index('y')['id']
df['pairs'] = df['pairs'].map(lambda x: [d[y] for y in x])
```

Result

```
    id  y       pairs
0  111  0       [111]
1  222  1  [222, 444]
2  333  3  [111, 333]
3  444  4       [444]
```